# why python modules used in power BI desktop not working in power BI service

Tags: python, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a python visual code which is working when ran in power BI desktop.
but when i published the same to power BI service and try to run, its throwing "Modlue Not found" error.
What might be the reason and how to overcome this error.

I'm importing below modules in my script

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
import glob
import time
from time import sleep
import requests
from itertools import product
```

I tried installing requests again but it says
[image]

but still it throwing ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' error

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation has a list of packages that are supported in the online service:
[Python packages that are supported in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-python-packages-support#python-packages-that-are-supported-in-power-bi).

You can request support for a new package here:
[Power BI Ideas](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/)

Answer (score 0):

> what might be the reason

Because your code is run in a multi-tenant SaaS service and so must run in a strict security sandbox.  Allowing arbitrary packages, and in particular allowing outbound network access with the `requests` package, makes the security of this sandbox harder to enforce.

Comment: so what would be the solution David, any workaround?

Comment: so what would be the solution David, any workaround?

Comment: Well, don't use the requests module in your python visual script.  If you need to get data, do it in Power Query and make it part of your  model.

Comment: is their a way where i can select from filters and pass the selection to power BI desktop and run the python scripts?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You can pass model data to the python visual by just adding the fields to the visual.  They will appear in a pandas dataframe. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-visuals

Comment: i meant like i was able to import requests and run it in power BI desktop, so is their a way i will pass values from power BI service to desktop and run the python code

Comment: No there is not.